# How to change colour of a 7-segment display using the Arduino

Tags: arduino, 7segmentdisplay, colour

[image: My 7_segment Display]

Is it possible to change colour of a 7-segment display using an Arduino Uno?

Comment: While the Arduino does a good job to make some things simple, it can't do magic.

Comment: *which* 7 segment display? Datasheet?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely no, in any case not in software.

Displays like this are usually single color, some are dual color, at most. The colors are physical properties of the LEDs and can't be changed. If you want arbitrary colors you need a red-green-blue triplet of LEDs for each segment, and I've never seen any of those.

Like I said *some* displays are dual color, for instance red-green, and they will have two common connections (like common cathode), one for red and one for green. It's highly unlikely that the display you show will be dual color.

Comment: http://www.adafruit.com/products/1399

Comment: Googling for *"RGB 7-segment" arduino* leads to [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLOVizCHysE) and other relevant sources of information. You'll need multiple shift-registers to handle the 22 IO connections per digit.